# rails jquery autocomplete is not working when trying to set limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I followed other solutions which are already answered for similar question. So I modified my jquery code accordingly as follows:

**jquery**

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, res) {
    var arraySource = $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source');
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(arraySource, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

This didn't work. But my other code where I did not implement array limitation works fine.:

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
     source: $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source')
});
```

**html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :manufacturer_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Manufacturer.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

Comment: change,  `response(results.slice(0, 10));` to  `res(results.slice(0, 10));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have taken `req`,`res` in the method parameter, but  `request` and `response` in the code. which is giving you the issue.

So, change the code to below.

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, res) {
    var arraySource = $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source');
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(arraySource, req.term);
    res(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```